# Multiple Actors in the same row Table Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Hello I'm using Libgdx And table with scene2d. I'm trying to add a few image buttons to the same row but what I'm getting is that the first image is centered in the middle and other two are pushed to the side , that also ruins my table (spacing)
Is there any method to add multiple Actors to the same row ?

Comment: How does the code of your table look like?

Comment: Nevermind I got around this problem

Answer (score 7):

I got around this problem with using multiple tables (Remember things are drawn in order they're added to stage). The problem here was that I had buttons with the size off almost all screen so  the elements in table could've only used those cells (One cell was the size of the screen)

Comment: +!, You came back and answered your own question when you found the solution to help others. More users need to do this, thanks.